# Batch append features with custom attributes

Tags: arcpy, field-mapping

I have a directory with 2,000+ subdirectories that contain shapefiles submitted by project managers through a web form. Some contain additional subdirectories that hold the shapefiles as follows:

`L:\uploads\102154682654842\14-52-63.shp` or `\102151486584621\project\14-59-22.shp`

The submitted shapefiles have no attribute field standards, so the field names are comletely random.

I would like to append the shapefiles to a feature class and assign the directory folder name (which is a unique number) to the master feature class ID field and the shapefile name `project.shp` to the master shapefile name field, such that the master feature class attribute table looks like this:

```
        ID       |   Name   |
 ----------------|----------|
 102154682654842 | 14-52-63 |
 ----------------|----------|
 102151486584621 | 4-59-22  |
 ----------------|----------|
```

I can parse those strings with os.walk

And I can append the shapefiles to the master feature class using something like this:

```
import arcpy, os

inputFolder = r"L:\Uploads"
#filelist = list()
errorcount = 0
passcount = 0

# traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and files as files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputFolder):
    path = root.split('/')
    arcpy.env.workspace = root
    features = arcpy.arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='polygon')
    #filelist.append(features)

    try:
        passcount += 1
        arcpy.Append_management(features, "L:\Test.gdb\Polygon", "NO_TEST","","")
#### ASSIGN path[index] to featureclass.Id and feature to featureclass.Name HERE! ####
        print "Append successful: ", path, features
        print "successful count: ",passcount

    except Exception, e:        
    errorcount += 1
    print "Failed to append: ", path, features
    print 'for the following reasons: '+ str(e)
    print "error number: ",errorcount
```

**Is there a way to add these attributes to the master feature class, through field mapping or other data management methods via arcpy?**

Comment: Not answering you question, but for better performance on searching directories, look at installing better walk or scandir instead of os.walk which i find painfully slow. https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Append geoprocessing tool, what I'd do is change the append portion to something more like (pseudo-code to follow, adjust names/paths/syntax accordingly):

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(masterFeatureClassPath, ['Shape@','ID','Name']) as ic:
    for featureClass in features:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(path,featureClass), ['Shape@']) as sc:
            for row in sc:
                ic.insertRow([row[0],folderName,featureClass])
```

Hopefully that helps at least give you an idea of a concept you could use to hopefully meet your needs.  If you need a bit more help fitting it into your specific code, I could maybe help with that a bit more, just let me know.

Data Access module cursor info is available at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm and http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm